# Web scraping with selenium to txt

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I would scrape ids from this page https://www.flashscore.co.uk/football/russia/premier-league/results/
Then replace   `g_1_` with  `https://www.flashscore.com/match/`  and import these urls to txt file.

I used this code

```
matches=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'g_1_')]")))

for match in matches:
    g1 = matches.replace("g_1_", "https://www.flashscore.com/match/")
    print(g1)
```

But I got this error

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

[id that i want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKSMh.png)

Comment: you have a typo. should be `g1 = match.replace("g_1_", "https://www.flashscore.com/match/")` ; NOT `matches.replace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as stated in the comments, `.replace()` is a method to be applied on a string. You have `matches`, which is a list object (of WebElements) which throws the error `'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`' You need to iterate through your list of WebElements, which you did define with `for match in matches:`, and then grab the id attribute as a string with `.get_attribute()` in order to use the `replace()` method.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


#Initializing the webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#Uncomment the line below if you'd like to scrape without a new Chrome window every time.
#options.add_argument('headless')

#Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://www.flashscore.co.uk/football/russia/premier-league/results/'
driver.get(url)
matches=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'g_1_')]")))

for match in matches:
    g1 = match.get_attribute('id')
    g1 = g1.replace("g_1_", "https://www.flashscore.com/match/")
    print(g1)
    
driver.close()
```

You could also combine that into a one-liner

`g1 = match.get_attribute('id').replace("g_1_", "https://www.flashscore.com/match/")`

**Output:**

```
https://www.flashscore.com/match/hWhb9Uyh
https://www.flashscore.com/match/rLoB6SLA
https://www.flashscore.com/match/zer38lib
https://www.flashscore.com/match/Eos77864
https://www.flashscore.com/match/4zzK46jN
https://www.flashscore.com/match/tdkfAAMo
https://www.flashscore.com/match/MBpF5nyH
https://www.flashscore.com/match/IwvO3Q5T
https://www.flashscore.com/match/nysS6yGg
https://www.flashscore.com/match/f1pz5Fp6
https://www.flashscore.com/match/jTwq3gFI
https://www.flashscore.com/match/QLhJ8cos
https://www.flashscore.com/match/0voW5eVa
https://www.flashscore.com/match/Yiqv4ZaC
https://www.flashscore.com/match/4CiN7H0m
https://www.flashscore.com/match/Sh1CoRqo
```

Comment: _...use .`replace()` on each element..._ is completely wrong and misleading. `replace()` replaces a specified phrase with another specified phrase only.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

...implies that in your program you have invoked `replace()` method on a *list*, where as [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) method replaces a **specified** phrase with another specified phrase.

You need to invoke `replace()` method on each of the element's text from the *list*.

---

### Solution

Instead of collection the elements, you can collect the texts/phrases from the element and create the *list*. Effectively your code block will be:

```
match_texts = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'g_1_')]")))]
for match_text in match_texts:
    g1 = match_text.replace("g_1_", "https://www.flashscore.com/match/")
    print(g1)
```

Comment: Now I got this error `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: Added picture with id that I want to scrape

Comment: @natamay462 Check out the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: 15.08. 19:00
FK Rostov
0
 - 
2
Zenit
(0 - 1)
..ecc

I have this return, instead I would have a list of urls. First: https://www.flashscore.co.uk/match/hWhb9Uyh
..ecc

Comment: @natamay462 This answer was to address the error _AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'_. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.